# Как заполнить селект значениями из функции

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, html-select

Делаю калькулятор для сайта на CMS Joomla. Калькулятор для расчёта стоимости автомобиля. Функция, которая приведена ниже, не работает, не заполняет селект значениями, хотел спросить у вас.
Код функции:

```
function f() {
    obem = document.getElementById("ob").value;
    if (obem <= 1000) {
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options.length = 0;
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[0] = new Option("Возраст машины", "0", true, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[1] = new Option("3-5 лет", "1.5", false, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[2] = new Option("старше 5 лет", "3", false, false);
    }
    if (obem <= 1500) {
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options.length = 0;
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[0] = new Option("Возраст машины", "0", true, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[1] = new Option("3-5 лет", "1.7", false, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[2] = new Option("старше 5 лет", "3.2", false, false);
    }
    if (obem <= 1800) {
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options.length = 0;
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[0] = new Option("Возраст машины", "0", true, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[1] = new Option("3-5 лет", "2.5", false, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[2] = new Option("старше 5 лет", "3.5", false, false);
    }
    if (obem <= 2300) {
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options.length = 0;
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[0] = new Option("Возраст машины", "0", true, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[1] = new Option("3-5 лет", "2.7", false, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[2] = new Option("старше 5 лет", "3.5", false, false);
    }
    if (obem <= 3000) {
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options.length = 0;
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[0] = new Option("Возраст машины", "0", true, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[1] = new Option("3-5 лет", "3", false, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[2] = new Option("старше 5 лет", "4.8", false, false);
    } else {
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options.length = 0;
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[0] = new Option("Возраст машины", "0", true, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[1] = new Option("3-5 лет", "3.6", false, false);
      document.calcForm.vekauto.options[2] = new Option("старше 5 лет", "5.7", false, false);
    }
  }
```

Сама форма:

```
<div id="calcForm">
          <table width="900px">
            <tr>
              <td width="40%" style="font-size: 14px;">
                <h3>Стоимость автомобиля в Германии</h3>Укажите стоимость автомобиля в Германии (цена указывается в евро).
                Брутто - цена с НДС, Нетто - цена без НДС. Эту стоимость вы можете узнать на сайтах:
                <a href="http://mobile.de">mobile.de</a>,
                <a href="http://autoskout24.de">autoskout24.de</a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="price">евро</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size: 14px;">
                <h3>Таможенные платежи</h3>Объем двигателя, в кубических сантиметрах (целое число, например - 2496)</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="ob" id="ob" onKeyUp="f()">куб.см.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size: 14px;">
                <h3>Возраст</h3>Возраст автомобиля (от 3 до 5 лет или старше)</td>
              <td>
                <select type="vekauto" name="vekauto" size="1">
                  <option value="0">Возраст машины</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size: 14px;">
                <h3>НДС</h3>Возврат НДС:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="radio" name="nds" value="600">&nbsp;&nbsp;Возврат НДС (цена брутто)
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="nds" value="0">&nbsp;&nbsp;Нет возврата (цена нетто)
                <br>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size: 14px;">
                <h3>Стоимость автомобиля в Москве</h3>Цена автомобиля после доставки из Германии и прохождения всех таможенных
                процедур:</td>
              <td style="font-size: 22px; color: #31a9e9!important;">
                <div id="itog" style="border: 1px solid #ffffff; width: 100px!important; padding: 10px 40px; text-align: center; display: block; width: 100%;display: none;">{totalprice}&nbsp;Евро</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h3>Рассчитать стоимость</h3>
              </td>
              <td style="font-size: 18px;text-align: center;">
                <a href="javascript: look('itog')">Расчёт</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Скажите пожалуйста, в чём причина того, что селект не заполняется значениями?

Comment: Да, оказывается я не заметил, срабатывает действительно только последнее значение. Подскажите пожалуйста, как поправить так, чтобы все значения работали?

Answer (score 1):

Хотя бы потому, что:

```
Timestamp: 19.04.2013 2:36:00
Error: TypeError: document.calcForm is undefined
Source File: http://127.0.0.1/test.html
Line: 12
```

И вообще, что за инпуты без `<form>`? Что такое `<select type="vekauto"`?

P.S. Интересно, когда-нибудь будет услышана эта мантра: "пользуйтесь отладчиком, пользуйтесь отладчиком, пользуйтесь отладчиком..."

Comment: Понимаете, дело в том, что я это всё делаю в компоненте FormCalc, а в нём, если мне не изменяет память, нет необходимости прописывать теги <form> и </form>

Comment: А какое отношение какие-то компоненты имеют к "необходимости прописывать form"? В любом случае первая проблема не в этом, и отлавливается она в отладчике за полторы секунды. Намного быстрей, чем набирается текст вопроса :)

Comment: вот сейчас прописал теги <form name="calcForm"> и </form>, но функция так и не работает...

Comment: вот ссылка на калькулятор: http://bmw97.ru/poschitat-stoimost-avto

Comment: Во-первых, у вас зачем-то две формы calcForm. Во-вторых, если посмотрите внимательно на расстановку else, то увидите, что срабатывают только 2 последних условия (либо <= 3000, либо последнее)

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, убрал сейчас <div id="calc"> и </div> и калькулятор заработал корректно. Если вам несложно, попробуйте посчитать. Я проверил, вроде работает правильно